# R: Spread data.frame/tibble with shared keys and missing data

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I have a two-column table, that I want to spread. I know that it is a very popular and well-explored topic here, however, I tried several approaches and didn't get what I wanted. Any suggestions and complaints are welcomed.

My table is filled with data of three women. In total there are 5 categories, and in general, each is filled with value. But some of the women' data are missing, what results in an absence of the whole row - please notice that `Jane` miss information about `weight`.

```
a = data.frame(categories = c("name", "sex", "age", "weight", "high", 
                              "name", "sex", "age", "high", 
                              "name", "sex", "age", "weight", "high"),
               values = c("Emma", "female", "32", "72", "175",
                          "Jane", "female", "28", "165",
                          "Emma", "female", "42", "63", "170")) 

   categories values
1        name   Emma
2         sex   female
3         age     32
4      weight     72
5        high    175
6        name   Jane
7         sex female
8         age     28
9        high    165
10       name   Emma
11        sex female
12        age     42
13     weight     63
14       high    170
```

I would like to obtain from `categories` - columns and from `values` - rows. But there are two main problems:

1) keys are shared - two Emmas (thus I cannot use `spread` or `reshape`)

2) some categories may be missing - as in the case of Jane's weight (thus I cannot use `pivot` or `split`)

In the end, I would like to reshape data to get a table like this one:

```
     name  sex    age  weight  high
     Emma  female 32   72      175
     Jane  female 28   NA      165
     Emma  female 42   63      170
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `'name'` is always present for each entry, we can create an identifier column and reshape using  `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(categories == 'name')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = categories, values_from = values) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

#  name  sex    age   weight high 
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1 Emma  female 32    72     175  
#2 Jane  female 28    NA     165  
#3 Emma  female 42    63     170
```

Same logic in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(a), cumsum(categories == 'name')~categories, value.var = 'values')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all entries start with `name` and playing around in base R with `magrittr` for cleanliness:

```
library(magrittr)
split(a, cumsum(a$categories == "name")) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) setNames(x[[2L]], x[[1L]])[unique(a$categories)]) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  data.frame()

  name    sex age weight high
1 Emma female  32     72  175
2 Jane female  28   <NA>  165
3 Emma female  42     63  170
```

Similarly playing with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
split(a, cumsum(a$categories == "name")) %>% 
  lapply(transpose, make.names = "categories") %>% 
  rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
```